# Chromedriver fails - OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xunit

I have just started using C# with Selenium and XUnit.
I just have this simple code to open a URL but it keeps failing.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Xunit;

namespace LearningCSharp
{
    public class FirstTest : IDisposable
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        [Fact]
        public void ChromeMethod()
        {    
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception while stopping Chrome..." + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I execute the following command in the terminal :

```
dotnet test
```

Chrome browser opens properly but closes immediately without getting to the URL asked.
Then i get the following stack trace at the line with GoToUrl():

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.49]
LearningCSharp.FirstTest.ChromeMethod [FAIL]        
X LearningCSharp.FirstTest.ChromeMethod [989ms]                               
Error Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : invalid argument (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Stack Trace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary 2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
```

I'm using a MAC OS 10.14. Chrome version 78. Visual Studio Community 2019. And here are the packages I'm using via nuget:
[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcCvt.png)

Any idea why this error ?
Thank you.

Comment: Where are you mentioning the chrome driver path and setting the property for it?

Comment: Well, when I add the package Selenium.Webdriver.Chrome to my project. The ChromeDriver.exe is automatically added in the folder Bin of my project. I presume there is no need to specify the link where to find it. I have taken this example from a tutorial on internet that seems to work fine for him.

Comment: Probably you can follow :
https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html

Comment: I am not a C# person, but i think you need to specify the chromedriver path while creating the driver.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera It is not necessary provide driver path, unless you want to explicitly choose some other version or copy of the driver you have. If you have installed the nuget it copies the driver automatically.

Comment: Yes, my bad. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is not valid. Add `https://` before `www`. This should solve the problem.

As per [WebDriver specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#navigate-to):

> If url is not an absolute URL or is not an absolute URL with fragment or not a local scheme, return error with error code invalid argument.